# OSGi bundles outside Eclipse

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix, apache-karaf

I have developed some bundles using the OSGi Java Framework using Eclipse Indigo. There is a Main Bundle that depends on other bundles and which have the main program to run. If I try to run all the bundles in Eclipse everything works properly but if I save each bundle as a JAR and I launch the OSGi framework in the command line I got an exception `NoClassDefFoundError` when I am trying to start the Main bundle. The class that cannot find is a depency. The rest of the bundle get the status ACTIVE, Main bundle just RESOLVED.

I have created a bundle with all the libraries I am using (mysql connector, etc...) and I am importing this bundle in every bundle I need these libraries. I don't know if this is best way to achieve it. Also, I am using threads in my application and some of them uses methods from different bundles, could that be a the origin of the problem?

Has anyone any idea of what could I do? I have also to install the bundles in Apache Karaf and I have got the same result. Does it have to do with the start level of each bundle?

Comment: How are you exporting your Bundle?

Comment: Depending on the bundle I am exporting the whole bundle or just few packages, but for both I am using the MANIFEST.MF. This file for the main bundle is: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Main
Bundle-SymbolicName: MainBundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.xaptum.messageprocessor.main.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: whatever
Require-Bundle: XXXXXBundle;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 YYYYYBundle;bundle-version="1.0.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: com.some.imported.package,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"

Comment: I guess what Rohit was asking is how you're export your bundle to a jar file?!

Comment: Yes, I have exported them to a JAR files using the Plug-in Developement > Deployable plug-ins and fragments. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Also, I think my problem has to do with loading of the mysql jdbc connector in runtime. Somehow it does not find the library, so I receive a NullPointerException and then the object cannot be instantiated and the I receive the NoClassDefFoundError. Here it's a related link, but I have not found the solution yet: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix%3F

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out the problem. Eclipse has the parameter `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` set to * by default, but all the other OSGi Frameworks don't.

I am using Apache Karaf right now and I have changed the config.properties that it's located inside etc/ from the default value (org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot,sun.*,com.sun.*,javax.transaction,javax.transaction.*) to *. That make it work, but I am still trying to recognize the exact library that needs to be loaded because setting this parameter to * is discouraged.

To find more information: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_Eclipse_find_javax.swing_but_not_Felix%3F

Thanks and I hope this helps other people,